# Extract part of a filename

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a directory full of files named like CompanyName-SomeAlphaNumString.log.
I would like to get a directory listing of just:
`SomeAlhpaNumString      LastWriteTime`

I suspect I need a custom property in a Select-Object filter:
`gci *.log | select @{n="Name"; e={$_ <What goes here?> }}, LastWriteTime`

Do I need to incorporate a regex in to the custom property, or is there another way to do it?
Thanks for any ideas....

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
gci *.txt | select @{n="Name"; e={if ($_.Name -match "CompanyName-(\w+)") { 
  $matches[1] }}}, LastWriteTime
```

where

```
$_.Name -match "CompanyName-(\w+)")
```

selects the CompanyName followed by hypen and a word where the word is put into a backreference

```
$matches[1]
```

selects the match put into backreference 1

---

Alternatively, you can remove the if clause by piping the result of the -match to Out-Null

```
gci *.txt | select @{n="Name"; e={$_.Name -match "CompanyName-(\w+)" | Out-Null; { 
  $matches[1] }}, LastWriteTime
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the Name is always blank.  I tried simplifying the custom property to `gci *.log | select @{n="Name"; e={$n}}, LastWriteTime | Select -First 5`, but get the same result.

Comment: Looks like `e={$n ...` should be `e={$_.Name ...`.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Now, to refine the SomeAlphaNumString match to only those strings that start with `AA` or `BB`....

Comment: Sorry, the $n was a leftover artifact of my own tries. You are right, it should be $_.Name. Answer edited.

Comment: You can try to change the regex to `CompanyName-((\w)\2\w+)`.